# Is there any issue if I don't use setState in willReceiveProps?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

**Insdead of using `setState` in `componentWillReceiveProps`, I just set the props to component's local property directly:**

```
class Inventory extends React.PureComponent {
  pieData = {};

  doSomeTransition = (pieData) => {

  };

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.productionOverview !== nextProps.productionOverview) {
      this.pieData = this.doSomeTransition(nextProps.productionOverview);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Production chartData={this.pieData} />
    );
  }

}
```

The `<Production />` component re-render well as every time `props. productionOverview`changes.

I feel like this is a wrong way but I can't tell why, because all the components work well as expected.

Answer (score 1):

`componentWillReceiveProps` is usually used to update your React component state when the props have changed. Which is why you will usually see `setState` inside that function.

That being said there is nothing wrong in calling something else, it all depends on the type of operation you are actually doing inside `doSomeTransition` ...

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you will experience any obvious side effects but you will not have any guarantees on when the property's value is actually updated/modified whereas utilizing the `this.state` you know the state is being handled in accordance to the [state's lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#what-should-go-in-state).

Comment: Well, then I guess we should consider using `state` and `setState` as a kind of 'constraint' in this situation